# Minecraft title in an area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am running a forge server and i need to display certain titles to a player when he/she enters an area. I have searched for tutorials on how to do this but to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all? The only ways I can think of doing this are: Command Blocks, modding Minecraft or CraftBukkit/Bukkit/Spigot plugins (assuming you're using [the old version of] Sponge or Cauldron). Not being able to find a tutorial to do what you want won't help. We need you to actually attempt something for us to help you properly.

Comment: I have tired everything i can. I have not found ANY plugins on this for forge. And it is a forge only server. THAT is why i am asking for help. Its not like i am lazy, I have been trying for 5 days!!

Comment: I'll give you some clues: Use Command Blocks, scoreboards (for keeping track), the `r=__,x=__,y=__,z=__` (to detect who's in/outside that "area") selector filter and `/title` (to show your titles). Once you have some tangible progress/attempt, I'll post you a full answer.

Comment: Sir, Please try to understand,
i am in a hurry to get this server running thats why i am posting the question here.
i dont know how to use /title and use command blocks like a pro...I dont have time for looking at tutorials and finding answer. I AM REQUESTING FOR THE SOLUTION BECAUSE THIS HERE IS A ONE TIME THING.
Please do try to understand, If i had the luxury to go through tutorials and understand how to do this. Its an immediate requirement. If i had the time i would definitly learn from the tutorials and not get insulted here by arrogant people acting high and mighty

Comment: One thing to note: your emergencies are not OUR emergencies. We don't care how quickly you need this; all we care about is how useful the question will be in the future. Showing effort is not required, but you'll get a much better reception if you do. Telling us you've tried is useless; *show us*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Have you tried using command blocks?

*You can give your command block using: `/give @p minecraft:command_block 1`.*

This only requires one repeated chain to fulfil.

Basically, we create variables to track:

- Who is in the area you want your message displayed.
- Who has the message been played to.

And what we do is:

- When a player enters our trigger area, we mark them as 'in the area'.
- Display our title to all players 'in the area' and without a 'executed' mark.
- Mark all players in the area as executed.
- When a player leaves the area, remove their 'executed' mark so that the title can execute again.
- Reset the titles of anyone outside the area and has executed.

### 1. Create your scoreboards to keep track of players.

```
/scoreboard objectives add inArea dummy
/scoreboard objectives add executed dummy
```

### 2. Create your logic to detect the players.

(This is in a command block chain starting with a repeater command block)

```
/scoreboard players set @a inArea 0
/scoreboard players set @a[r=__,x=__,y=__,z=__] inArea 1
/scoreboard title reset @a[score_inArea=0,score_executed_min=1] clear
/scoreboard title reset @a[score_inArea=0,score_executed_min=1] reset
/scoreboard players set @a[score_inArea=0] executed 0
```

*If you would like a cuboid area, use:*

```
/scoreboard players set @a inArea 0
/scoreboard players set @a[x=__,y=__,z=__,dx=__,dy=__,dz=__] inArea 1
/scoreboard title reset @a[score_inArea=0,score_executed_min=1] clear
/scoreboard title reset @a[score_inArea=0,score_executed_min=1] reset
/scoreboard players set @a[score_inArea=0] executed 0
```

- `executed` is the scoreboard to store whether or not a player has the title executed on them.
- `inArea` is whether or not the player is in the area.

Basically:

1. Set all players to be marked 'outside' of the area.
2. Remove `executed` mark from anyone outside the area so that our trigger can run again.
3. Mark all players inside the area as 'inside' the area.
4. Reset titles of those outside of the area and had the title executed on.

Replace the `__` with the radius/volume/XYZ of the check area and the origin.

### 3. Display your title to eligible players.

(In the same command chain as Step 2, only continued. Basically, append these to the end of the chain in Step 2.)

```
/title @a[score_inArea_min=1,score_executed=0] times <Insert title command args>
/title @a[score_inArea_min=1,score_executed=0] title <Insert title command args>
/title @a[score_inArea_min=1,score_executed=0] subtitle <Insert title command args>
/scoreboard players @a[score_inArea_min=1] executed 1
```

Basically:

1. If the player is inside the area and hasn't been executed yet, show him the title.
2. Mark all players inside the trigger area as executed.

If done right, you should have a repeat command block, followed by a chain of chain command blocks with the commands in the order shown.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you so much for the amazing presenting with the amazing logic...But when i tried i was getting an error in the command block.

Comment: on executing this line in the command block , 
/title @a[score_inArea_min=1,score_executed=0] title {"text":"In Area"} I was getting
[19:27:45] Selector '@a[score_inArea_min=1,score_executed=0]' found nothing
Am i doing something wrong? Sorry if this seems to be stupid but i am a beginner...

Comment: @AnilSimon I must have gotten a few filters incorrect. Feel free to fix them on your own in the meantime. I'll attempt a bug fix tomorrow.

Comment: Okie..i will ry my best...since i am a beginner i dont have much hope.So your help once you are able to would be immensly appreciated

Comment: hey...i tried this out but am not able to figure it out what the issue...can you help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

To have a message always display while you are in an area you could do this.

### Run this once:

```
/title @a times 0 3 0
```

### Put this on a looping command block:

```
/execute @a[x=<x>,y=<y>,z=<z>,dx=<x1>,dy=<y2>,dz=<z2>] ~ ~ ~ title @p title {"text":"In Area"}
```

But replace x,y,z,x1,y2,z2 with the coordinates you want the area to be and change "In Area" to whatever text you would like to display.