# Showing a title when entering a specific area in minecraft java realms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm trying to get names to appear when entering an area, but all I manage to get is the title either being stuck on screen, or it not working at all.
I've researched a bit, and found some posts on here but when I tried the recommended stuff it didn't really work.

I've figured out a method that works pretty well, with the only issue that the title is, like mentioned above, stuck on my screen for eternity.

### **What I have so far:**

*(I set up a scoreboard "inArea" and a dummy player "#areaman". The dummy player has the score 1.)*

1. a single repeater command block:  `execute if entity @p[x=,y=,z=,dx=,dy=,dz=] run scoreboard players set @p inArea 1`
2. another repeater command block at the beginning of a command block chain: `execute as @a if score @p inArea >= #areaman inArea 1`
3. `title @p[x=,y=,z=,dx=,dy=,dz=] title "Wizard Tower"` and `scoreboard players set @p inArea 0`
4. added a seperate repeater to keep the dummy player's score at 0: `scoreboard players set #areaman inArea 1`

I've tried the top answer from [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308068/minecraft-title-in-an-area), but it gave me error messages so I just experimented with /execute and the scoreboards. All I know is that the issue is somewhere within the command chain.

I figured out how to make the title dissapear when leaving the area and edited the code accordingly, however, when remaining in the area the title still won't go away.
Any help with that would be gladly apprechiated, I will update this post if i figure out something myself tho :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a Minecraft map title show only once?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391824/how-do-i-make-a-minecraft-map-title-show-only-once) Also, when using `execute as (entity)`, make sure to refer to it as `@s` later on rather then `@p`.

Comment: Yeah! I added it and as far as i can see it works
thanks!